# patent renewal /re-application

Tags: patent-applications

I have designed a unique instrument , applied for temporary patent in UK and EU , got it granted and thereafter , due to lack of capital , the temporary patent expired after 18 months. I dont understand why I cant patent it now if 1) no one else has and 2) I designed it so the "novelty" remains the same unlike if someone else took it and claimed it as theirs after the temp patent expiration.
Please explain.

Comment: Interesting, I’ve never heard of a “temporary” patent.

Comment: By "temporary patent" do you mean provisional patent application (though that's for 12 months, and not available in the UK or EP)? Or do you mean a utility model (which is not really temporary, and is not available in the UK or EP, but some EP states)? Or do you mean a patent application that you didn't pay fees for (which I guess could expire at 18 months in some cases)? At this stage, I fear it's too unclear to answer.

Comment: Apparently, rather than have provisional applications, the UK allows a relatively long delay in paying any filing fees and the system has been referred to as a "temporary patent application".

Comment: Was it published or have you told anyone about it without an understanding of confidentially? If neither, novelty may not be broken and you could file again.